# Input box will not "forget" the first value it gets Firefox 20.0

Tags: javascript, firefox, input

The problem I have is with an input box not forgetting the first input it gets.  It then feeds it back even when the content should have been over written by a new input.  The code I am using works fine with IE8 the problem is seen with Firefox 20.0.

I am working entirely in Javascript.  There is no HTML beyond a body.

I use this to set up my input box:

```
addElementWithIdButNoNode("input","manimp","div42"); // add input box
addElementWithNodeAndId("button","Set","div42","setButton"); //add "set" button
document.getElementById("setButton").onclick=showIt;
```

"manimp" is the ID and the below successfully captures  what is entered first  time around as "theMainVar".

```
function showIt()
  {
  theMainVar=manimp.value;
  theMainVar=parseFloat(theMainVar);
  alert(theMainVar);
  }
```

The problem is that if you run this again in Firefox you can enter any value you like but the alert comes back with what you entered the first time around.

You can manually sent the "manimp.value" to something else in javascript and it does change but it then stays stuck at this changed value.

I need a "reset manimp so it can accept a new value from the input box function"

I have had a look around and found lots of "reset()" and "clear()" funcitons but nothing works for me.

The same thing happens if I swap the input box for a drop down.

I'm new to Javascript so if the fix seem obvious to you, maybe it is!

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do, and more important, how do you do it. Please create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: May you sometimes use the `value` attribute, sometimes the DOM `.value` property?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the 'manimp' element inside your function, probably the value is referenced when the function is declared. So, inside your function use

theMainVar = document.getElementById('manimp').value;